# Eloquent hasOne seems to be updating wrong table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting an integrity constraint violation on an update to my users table when I am adding the current User to a Product. I am also using uuids instead of auto-incrementing so it adds another layer of complexity. I think I might be declaring the relationships wrong.

The error looks like it is trying to update the users table tryi`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: users.uuid (SQL: update "users" set "uuid" = ?, "updated_at" = 2019-09-24 13:18:05 where "uuid" = 8ee98fac-11f7-5114-b9f1-772fe9732a49)`

**users table**

- uuid

**User.php**

```php
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'user_uuid', 'uuid');
    }
```

**products table**

- uuid
- user_uuid

**Product.php**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use uuidTrait;

    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    public $incrementing = FALSE;

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'uuid', 'user_uuid');
    }
    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function(Product $instance){
            $instance->user()->save(auth()->user());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need `$instance->user()->save(auth()->user());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the uuid of the current user

```
    static::creating(function(Product $instance){
        if(empty($instance->uuid)){
            $instance->uuid = auth()->user()->user_uuid;
        }
    });
```

or you use the `associate` [function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

```
$product = new Product;
//...
$product->save();
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->associate($product);
$user->save();
```

Comment: That section is to create the uuid for the instance,

`$instance->user()->save(auth()->user());` should be getting the user model and attaching it. Can I not do that here, but have to pull the uuid out of the model?

Comment: as you can see `user()->save() ` updates the current user, you need the current user uuid to save to your product table

Comment: But `$instance->user()` is the user relationship of the product. So normally `$product_instance->relationship()->save($related_model)` should add $related_model to the to the relationship definded in the relationship function. Unless I am reading relationships wrong.

Could I go the other way? Invoke the user model and then attach the product with the product's relationship? Or is relationship attachment better done manually in the create stage?